# Java: regexp to match \n with only one \

Tags: java, regex, newline

I need a regexp, that matches `\n` everywhere, except `\\\\\n` (`n` with multiple `\`) Every other variant is suitable. 
For example:

- `SOMETEXT\nANOTHERTEXT` - want `\n` here to match my regexp
- `\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n` - this shouldn't match
- `\\\\\\\sdfsdfsdf\\\n` - this shouldn't match
- `\\\\\\s\n` - this should match
- `\n` - this should match

Sorry, if it's a dumb question, I tried googling, but with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a **Negative Lookbehind** here.

```
(?<!\\)\\n
```

See [**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/qR2fN4)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How to make it work in Java?

Comment: Seems your solution is what I tried to write...: +1

Comment: In java, try `(?<!\\\\)\n`

Answer (score 1):

Tried using `"\\n"` as a pattern?

For clarification the first `\` is just for escaping special character

Comment: yes, I know. Strings like "\\\\\\n" match, though they shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

You need negative lookahead. Try something like this: `(?!\\)\n`. Probably you have to duplicate the slashes, i.e. write something like `(?!\\\\)\n`